# Can we have a way to distinguish between deleted and undeleted posts on the review history page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-posts, review-history

**Can you guess which of these closed posts are deleted?**

[image: Screenshot from https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history]

This screenshot is taken from https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history. Several of the posts in this screenshot are deleted, for good reasons. As it currently stands there is no way to see which posts are deleted, and which aren't. Can the difference be made visible?

Comment: Yes please. [Very rough sketch of how I would like to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wBOF.png), even using the new design. :-)

Comment: AFAIK, these were marked in red, like on your user activity page.

Comment: Is this for close review queue only, or all queues?

Comment: @zcoop98: Personally, I'm guessing the request applies to all queues, since the same behavior seems to be true of all queues.

Comment: Just wanted to add that as a >10k user, I _do_ see deleted posts differentiated in the list, eg. when I view a queue history on Stack Overflow (with 2k rep), [deleted post titles are just text, and not linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFq0n.png).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great suggestion and thanks [for the mockup Shadow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376495/can-we-have-a-way-to-distinguish-between-deleted-and-undeleted-posts-on-the-revi#comment1254914_376495).  This shipped on prod and now looks like this when viewing deleted posts that show up in the review task history:

[image: Review Task History Records with deleted indicator]

Comment: We appreciate the changes, but instead of such a large indicator and text would it be better if it were simply a red square with the white can; or one of these Unicode characters: ️ ,  , ❌ ,  ,  or  ? --- Here is a new mockup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HtIm.png

Comment: @Rob whoops, this is on me. *blush*

Comment: Reasonable Idea @Rob - Icons without text can be hard to read/distinguish.  We did go through a couple design cycles on this internally just to think through what made the most sense.  I'll bring it back to the team, but my guess is we'd rather have it. Two things that I think are in favor of dropping it is that trash bin is reasonable well understood, and this page is mostly for super users who can learn what symbols mean what.  But as far as a design system, it's not super extensible if it just works in a one off case.

Comment: KyleMit, please note that I **moved** the text [from the icon to a separate text area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Fkz.png). It is *better* design to not repeat the same wording when it can be summarized (condensed) and actually explained in full. It leaves more space for the title (what you *came* to see) and it allows for **text translation** (without having to draw several icons for all our supported languages) which is easier to update. The small trashcan seems less jarring (garish) than the huge icon, whose purpose is not only obvious but completely explained in the upper right.

Comment: An **additional benefit**: if no posts have been deleted the upper right text indicates that the icon would be available, but is missing; perhaps some deleting is in order (by vote, or moderator) - otherwise a page without any deleted posts would leave the user wondering if the feature had been implemented on the site yet, with the upper right text it is certain.

Comment: P.S. I think users who don't have the privilege to see deleted posts will not be shown hyperlinks of the deleted posts.