# Please add a label for review audits in review history

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, review-history

Let's take a look at my First questions review history:

[image]

The [second task mentioned in the history](https://askubuntu.com/q/1387081) is a [review audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-questions/1204532). It would be great if we can use a label for review audits like we have a [label for deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377812).

We already have a label for review audits in the timeline of posts; we can perhaps use the same label.

[image]

I made a mock-up and here it is:

[image]

Comment: I kind of like this. Could be beneficial if it also denoted whether you passed or failed the audit in that little icon, such as "Audit: Passed". Whether this should only be visible on your own review list or also for others' is debatable, though in either case I feel like it'd be worthwhile for mods to be able to see this at a glance.

Comment: Also makes it easier for 10k+ users (who see everyone's reviews there) to catch users who game the system to robo-review while detecting and passing every audit.